# I need to maintain a multiple static lists of strings in Java for an NER Tagger

Tags: java, dictionary, nlp, hashtable

I'm working on a natural language processing project. I need to maintain multiple lists such as Most Common Cities, Most Common Names etc. I will check tokens against these list during the feature generation segment of my project. I am considering creating a static class with a collection of hash tables with look up methods for each list that returns a simple boolean.

Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That is one option, another one is a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). Both ways are plausible. In GATE's [HashGazetteer](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch13.html#x18-34500013.5) for instance, they have a set of hashmaps, each holding strings with specific length. One for strings with length 1, one for length 2, etc.

If you're looking for a practical solution I'd suggest you use an NLP framework. All of the frameworks I know have implementations of a dictionary: GATE, DkPro, nltk...

Comment: Thanks @Yasen. I ended up writing a perl script to generate "static" Java classes with HashSets in them. I'll go head and explore nlp frameworks and corpuses. An interesting problem I ran into was some kind of constraint on the length of a java method. I ended up having to split the list up into separate methods and have one top level method to populate the hashset.